# RealmSwiftPermission' is not managed by the Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

In my Realm Cloud, I have Realm `Locations` where I store `locations` for my map. Every user should have access to this Realm and get through query nearest annotations.

But I faced with a problem: Only administrators have permission for this, not regular users ( How it intended to be).

For solving this problem I add following code to my ViewController:

```
try! self.realm.write {
    let everyonePermission = self.realm.permissions.findOrCreate(forRoleNamed: "everyone")
    everyonePermission.canRead = true
    everyonePermission.canQuery = true
}
```

I planned to add this role to every user but I faced with another issue:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Object type 'RealmSwiftPermission' is not managed by the Realm. If using a custom `objectClasses` / `objectTypes` array in your configuration, add `RealmSwiftPermission` to the list of `objectClasses` / `objectTypes`.'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1845fad8c 0x1837b45ec 0x10122830c 0x101264100 0x101cb2308 0x100cf42bc 0x101cb13a8 0x100cf3ffc 0x100cf35dc 0x1027b11dc 0x1027b119c 0x1027b5d2c 0x1845a3070 0x1845a0bc8 0x1844c0da8 0x1864a5020 0x18e4dd758 0x100cf9720 0x183f51fc0)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

What should I do to resolve this? Probably there is another way to give permission for every user to access to that Realm?